# ArrayComputed: Groupby and computed properties not resolved from promises

Tags: ember.js

I have a group model that contains some bets from several user. Every user can have more than one bet. In order to display the end result I want to group the bets by user and then sum up the points. this is my bet model that contains the point logic:

```
    App.GameBet = DS.Model.extend({
    scoreT1: DS.attr(),
    scoreT2: DS.attr(),

    betRound: DS.belongsTo('betround'),
    game: DS.belongsTo('game', {async:true}),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async:true}),

    points: function(){
        var game = this.get('game');

        var sc1 = this.get('game.scoreT1');
        var sc2 = this.get('game.scoreT2');
        var b1 = this.get('scoreT1');
        var b2 = this.get('scoreT2');

        if(sc1 == b1 && sc2 == b2) {
            return 7;
        } else if ((sc1 - sc2) == (b1 - b2)) {
            return 5;
            // Exakte Punktzahl
        } else if ((sc1 - sc2) * (b1 - b2) > 0) {
            return 3;
            // Tendenz
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }.property('scoreT1', 'scoreT2', 'game.scoreT1', 'game.scoreT2')

});
```

This is working perfectly fine when I just render all bets with their points. But when I am using my own groupby ArrayComputeed function, it isn't working:

```
App.betGroupBy = function (dependentKey) {
    var options = {
        initialValue: Ember.A([]),

        initialize: function (array, changeMeta, instanceMeta) {
            return instanceMeta.previousKeys = {};
        },

        addedItem: function (accumulatedValue, item, changeMeta, instanceMeta) {
            console.log(item.get('id') + " " + item.get('points'));
            var user = item.get('user');
            var key = user.get('id');
            var group = accumulatedValue.findBy('key', key);
            if (!group) {
                group = Ember.Object.create({
                    key: key,
                    user: user,
                    bets: Ember.A([]),
                    betPoints: Ember.computed.mapBy('bets', 'points'),
                    points: Ember.computed.sum('betPoints')
                });
                accumulatedValue.pushObject(group);
            }
            group.get('bets').pushObject(item);
            instanceMeta.previousKeys[Ember.guidFor(item)] = key;
            return accumulatedValue;
        },

        removedItem: function (accumulatedValue, item, changeMeta, instanceMeta) {
            var key = item.get(property);
            var group = accumulatedValue.findBy('key', key);
            if (!group) {
                return;
            }
            var userBets = group.get('bets');
            userBets.removeObject(item);
            if (userBets.length === 0) {
                accumulatedValue.removeObject(group);
            }
            return accumulatedValue;
        }
    };
    return Ember.arrayComputed(dependentKey, options);
};
```

Somehow my "points" in the grouped function are always zero.
It seems that the promises are not early enough resolved or something.

Comment: Have you checked the isLoaded property of each GameBet?